# Custom ServiceHostFactory never called on Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have a WCF Service solution (NET 4) with custom ServiceHostFactory that works fine on my developer machine (Windows 8.1 and IIS 8.5) but I can't get it working on Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.5 for some reason. The WCF service itself works on Server 2012, but the ServiceHostFactory is never called. Is there a particular module that I should install via Add Roles or Features in Server 2012 in order to make it work?

```
public class InternalAHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        ServiceHost host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        host.Opening += new EventHandler(host_Opening);
        return host;
    }

    void host_Opening(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This is never called on Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5 but works on Windows 8.1 and IIS 8.5
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the line of config that would make the server use your factory?

Comment: I haven't specified it in the web.config, but it still works on my developer machine, and even on another server 2012, but just with this one particular server 2012 it doesn't work

Comment: I've specified Factory="Internal.InternalAHostFactory" in the .svc file

Answer (score 0):

Adding complete "WCF Services" feature set via the Server Manager solved this issue in my case.